# showing file count in jquery multifile

Tags: javascript

I'm using following file input plugin,[jquery multifile plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/)

[image]

but its not showing real time how many files selected

Comment: I don't understand. How can I know the error if you don't show us your implementation.. or where do you think is the problem..

Comment: though I added 3 files its showing file count as "No file choosen"

Comment: can you show your code.

Comment: Can you show us your implementation probably there is a problem in the validation ~!